# Copy response.text() from fetch api in Chrome DevTools to the clipboard

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, clipboard

I've tried using JS's copy() and creating an element/populating it with the data/copying the result. I cannot figure out how to get the response.text() to the clipboard.

The actual fetch is an XHR but the below example should suffice:

```
fetch('/readme.txt')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => console.log(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get response text and then copy it to the clipboard using another function:

```js
fetch('/readme.txt').then(
    response => response.text()
).then(
    text => {
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(text).then(
            () => console.log("Success!"),
            (err) => console.log("Error copying response text", err)
        )
    }
)
```

In old browsers `navigator.clipboard` can be unavailable, you can get more info about copying [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)